# Search Twitter tweets by #topic with distinct user

Tags: twitter

What is a good way to show the most-recent tweets on a #topic by distinct users? For example,  if five users have written a combined total of twenty tweets on #example, but one zealot has the fifteen most recent, I want only his latest.

Duplicate-elimination is a plus, because parrots are low value.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this with the Twitter Search API - you'll need to pull down the feed and do your own post-processing on it.

Comment: probably jetwick.com (open source) could help. I'm using ElasticSearch under the hood and I could explain how you could reach your requirement even within one query with the help of 2d-facets. Or you can simply query it more than once with normal facets.